# Where and how to define member variables? In header or implementation file?

Tags: c++

I have problems understanding the concept of classes and member variables in C++.
Given the following example:

File: Mems.h:

```
class Mems{

int n;
Mems();
};
```

File Mems.cpp:

```
class Mems{

Mems::Mems(){
    //Do something in constructor
}
};
```

I do not know, where I have to put my variables if I want them to stick to the object?

When I define them in the header-file I can't access them in the cpp File and vice versa.

Comment: _I cant access them in the cpp_ did you miss to include your header file??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to re-declare the class in the `.cpp` file. You only need to implement its member functions:

```
#include "Mems.h"
#include <iostream> // only required for the std::cout, std::endl example

Mems::Mems() : n(42)  // n initialized to 42
{
  std::cout << "Mems default constructor, n = " << n << std::endl;    
}
```

Note that usually you want the default constructor to be `public`. Members are `private` by default in C++ classes, and `public` in structs.

```
class Mems
{
 public:
  Mems();
 private:
  int n;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Mems
{
public:
  int n;
  Mems();
};
```

In this case, `n` is a member variable for your class `Mems`. Inside the class, you can access it like this:

```
Mems::Mems() //you don't actually need to use the class keyword in your .cpp file; just the class name, the double colon, and the method name is enough to mark this as a class method
{
  //Do something in constructor
  n = 5; //this sets the value of n within this instance of Mems
}
```

Outside the `Mems` class, you can access any public member variables like this:

```
Mems myMems;
int myNum;

myMems.n = 10; //this sets the value of n in this instance of the Mems class
myNum = myMems.n; //this copies the value of n from that instance of the Mems class
```

Comment: Hmmm, private constructor??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for reminding me. Been doing a lot of work with `struct` lately, and everything is public by default in there... edited my post to fix that.